# nginx.conf redirect multiple conditions

Tags: redirect, nginx

I want to redirect requests on two conditions using Nginx.

This doesn't work:

```
  if ($host = 'domain.example' || $host = 'domain2.example'){
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.domain.example/$1 permanent;
  }
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Many people are criticizing the use of 'if' blocks instead of separate server blocks, but in cases where adding a separate server block adds a lot of complexity it is a perfectly acceptable solution. E.g. for https you can avoid specifying all of the SSL config again.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

I had this same problem before. Because Nginx can't do complex conditions or nested if statements, you need to evaluate over 2 different expressions.

set a variable to some binary value then enable if either condition is true in 2 different if statements:

```
set $my_var 0;
if ($host = 'domain.example') {
  set $my_var 1;
}
if ($host = 'domain2.example') {
  set $my_var 1;
}
if ($my_var = 1) {
  rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.domain.example/$1 permanent;
}
```

Comment: This answer is relevant with new version of nginx I guess. I have trying for hours for rewrite rule to work, but I had to go with this approach. Though it looks messy but it works just fine. Thanks :)

Comment: @Jaap Most of the nginx IF problems are for using IF inside LOCATION, most  of the time, IF in server level are fine... they should still be avoid and replaced with location, geoip and maps when possible, but there are situations where you can not avoid it

Answer (score 25):

The correct way would be to use a dedicated server for the redirect:

```
server {
  server_name domain.example domain2.example;
  rewrite ^ http://www.domain.example$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. This causes nginx not to be able to re/start.

Comment: What's the error message you're getting?  What I posted wouldn't go in the same place as the if, since the if is already in a server.  It would be a sibling to the server block you already have.

Comment: @mark this is a new server, you have to remove domain.com and domain2.com from the existent config, to avoid duplicated server_names

Comment: I voted this up, because for one server it worked. On another multi-tennanted nginx server though, it did not. Odd

Answer (score 7):

another possibility would be

```
server_name domain.example domain2.example;
set $wanted_domain_name domain.example;
if ($http_host != $wanted_domain_name) {
    rewrite  ^(.*)$  https://$wanted_domain_name$1;
}
```

so it will redirect all to one specific but it's based on the use case I guess

Comment: this is actually not the recommended way to do it, because that `if ()` check now happens on every request. It's better to set up two server blocks, one of which (for the unwanted domain) only does a redirect.

Comment: @BenXO thank you, I know. Still it's a possibility :) as there are lots of others.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a declarative approach:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  `domain.example` `domain2.example`;
    return 301 $scheme://www.domain.example$uri;
}

server {
    listen       80  default_server;
    server_name  _;
    #....
}
```

Comment: this looks like a loop

Comment: Requests for domain.com or domain2.com are only matched by the first server stanza. Notice that this is an exact match; not a wildcard. Anything else is matched in the second server stanza. That's what makes it declarative.

Comment: @Unicornist: it's not a loop, because it's redirecting from `domain.com` or `domain2.com`, to `www.domain.com`. The `www` host is not matched by the first server block.

Answer (score 6):

> ### Rewriting multiple domains to a single domain and avoiding a looping condition in the browser.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.wanted_domain.example wanted_domain.example www.un_wanted_domain.example un_wanted_domain.example;
    if ($host = 'un_wanted_domain.example'){
       return 301 $scheme://www.wanted_domain.example$request_uri;
    }
    if ($host = 'www.un_wanted_domain.example'){
       return 301 $scheme://www.wanted_domain.example$request_uri;
    }
```

Comment: this should be avoid, no need to use IF where 2 (or more) different servers, one normal and another(s) for redirect are faster and cleaner

Answer (score 5):

I think the easiest way to do it it's just use regular expression:

```
if ($host ~ "domain.example|domain2.example") {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

But it's good only when you have only strings; for complex logic, sure, it is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Another version is to map it to one string and then evaluate it via regex. In this case the if condition is: `$arg_version && $request_method = "GET"`

```
map "$arg_version:$request_method" $bypass_cache {
  default 1;
  ~^(.+):GET$ 0;
}

location /  {
  if ($bypass_cache = 0) {
      expires max;
  }
  ...  
}
```