# current hosting from htaccess to user.ini

Tags: php, apache

I want to distinguish php flag to set based on current working hosting...

In htaccess I'm using this

```
<if "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'localhost' ">
    # PHP error handling for development servers
    php_flag display_startup_errors on
    php_flag display_errors on
    .......
</if>
<Elseif "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'mywebsite.com' ">
    .......
</Elseif>
```

How to do the same with user.ini ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nginx.conf redirect multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833238/nginx-conf-redirect-multiple-conditions)

Comment: @Justinas Not based on the Apache tag

Comment: No need. Set the php.ini file or user.ini file based on which host its on and leave it. Dont move it about like it was code